# PHP iconv greek/cyrillic transliteration does not work

Tags: php, internationalization, iconv, setlocale

i have the following test code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function t($text)
{
    echo "$text\n";
    echo "encoding: ", mb_detect_encoding($text), "\n";

    // transliterate
    $text = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text);
    echo "iconv: ", $text, "\n";
}

// Latvian alphabet
t('AĀBCČDEĒFGĢHIĪJKĶLĻMNŅOPRSŠTUŪVZŽ aābcčdeēfgģhiījkķlļmnņoprsštuūvzž');
// Greek alphabet
t('ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω');
// Cyrillic alphabet + some rarer versions
t('АБВГДЕЖЅЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТѸФХѠЦЧШЩЪꙐЬѢꙖѤЮѦѪѨѬѮѰѲѴ абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя');
```

and its output:

```
AĀBCČDEĒFGĢHIĪJKĶLĻMNŅOPRSŠTUŪVZŽ aābcčdeēfgģhiījkķlļmnņoprsštuūvzž
encoding: UTF-8
iconv: AABCCDEEFGGHIIJKKLLMNNOPRSSTUUVZZ aabccdeefgghiijkkllmnnoprsstuuvzz

ΑαΒβΓγΔδΕεΖζΗηΘθΙιΚκΜμΝνΞξΟοΠπΡρΣσςΤτΥυΦφΧχΨψΩω
encoding: UTF-8
iconv: 

АБВГДЕЖЅЗИІКЛМНОПҀРСТѸФХѠЦЧШЩЪꙐЬѢꙖѤЮѦѪѨѬѮѰѲѴ абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
encoding: UTF-8
iconv:
```

it essentially IGNOREs all greek and cyrillic characters. why?

i have tested on two environments, where `php -i | egrep "iconv (implementation|library)"` outputs either:

```
iconv implementation => libiconv
iconv library version => 1.11
```

or:

```
iconv implementation => libiconv
iconv library version => 1.13
```

i have also tried setting ivonv internal encoding to UTF-8, adding/removing the `setlocale` function, but all of no avail. iconv seems to recognise only latin and derived-from-latin characters.

**UPDATE**: It must be a problem with iconv as terminal command `echo 'ΑαΒβΓγΔδ' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` produces an error `iconv: (stdin):1:0: cannot convert`, while `echo 'āēī' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` works and outputs `aei`, as expected.

`iconv --version` outputs `iconv (GNU libiconv 1.14)` (besides the copyright information).

Answer (score 3):

use `ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT`

The iconv() stopped at the first illegar char, cutting off the string right there, which is the default behaviour of `iconv()`, so it did not respect the `//IGNORE` switch after the `//TRANSLIT`

Comment: @yes123 I don't know how you had tried. But, it works for the first case. Please read the PHP manual then you'll understand for which It'll work and for which it'll not.

Comment: yep, swapping `//IGNORE` with `//TRANSLIT` indeed doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Rifat, the first sample works also without the swap. iconv correctly removes all diacritics from letters ĀČĒĢĪĶĻŅŌŖŠŪŽ etc. please see the output log in my original question.

Comment: @ErnestsKarlsons OK, but still `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` is not the correct way as per documentation.

Comment: @ErnestsKarlsons, Sorry that I didn't notice your output carefully

Comment: On Mac OS X 10.6.8 with iconv library v1.11, both `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` and `//IGNORE//TRANSLIT` result in no output for the Greek and Cyrillic examples above. Not even with `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'el_GR.UTF-8');` neither with `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');` Both `el_GR.UTF-8` and `ru_RU.UTF-8` are verified to exists on the OS with `$ locale -a`.

Comment: Error on `echo "ΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ" π | iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT` ... can be corrected?

Comment: This will just ignore the cryllic letters