# Converting a UTF-8 greek letters to ASCII using ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT

Tags: iconv

I am using Linux terminal

```
echo -n "ΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ" | iconv -f utf-8 -t ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT
```

but error:  ilegal sequence.

Expected result: something as Α=A, Γ=G, Δ=D, Ε=E, Λ=L, etc.

PS: [similar to PHP's problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399442/287948) but  utf8 not accepted on terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it should be `echo -n "ΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"|iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT`. Note the capial UTF-8 and no IGNORE.

Second, there was a Greek transliteration table missing in glibc until recently. (iconv is part of glibc) [1]

If that bug still affects you there should be ????????????? given as output, but no error.

Anyway it is fixed for glibc 2.31 that is released on 2020-02-01 [2]

If you really need this before the new glibc makes into your distributive you could patch the glibc/locale/C-translit.h.in and recompile.

[1] https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12031

[2] https://sourceware.org/legacy-ml/libc-announce/2020/msg00001.html

---

NOTES

- UBUNTU and many other Linux use [`glibc` instead `libc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54054270/287948)
- on UBUNTU you can check version with the command `ldd --version` or `dpkg -l libc6`

Comment: Hi Digo, good answer, thanks. It is an old question, now I have other machines... Trying with UBUNTU 20 LTS: the direct copy/paste of your `echo -n "ΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"|iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` results in 
*"iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0"*

Comment: could you please try `/usr/bin/iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT <<< "ΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ"` and also check the libc version `find /lib -iname 'libc*.so'`

Comment: Hi, the suggested `/usr/bin/iconv` command produced the same error. The `find` no result. The only libc at /lib is `/lib/libc-client.so.2007e`

Comment: That’s odd. Yet I’m not an expert on the issue of how the particular OS is managing its glibc. So to really debug this what you’d need to do is to somehow find out what version of glibc is installed on your system. Another avenue is to download the latest glibc source and compile it locally. There’s a way to test it without replacing the binary version already installed .

Comment: PS: @Diego perhaps some confusion with **glibc**?  For example at Ubuntu 18 `ldd --version` = *"ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.2) 2.27"*. For another methods (compiling by gcc) see [this "linux check glibc" article](https://benohead.com/blog/2015/01/28/linux-check-glibc-version/)... But ideal is `inconv`  to say by it self... another bug if it not say.

Comment: Yes, as I said in my answer it is first fixed for glibc 2.31 that is released on 2020-02-01. So obviously you don't have the fixed version on your system yet.